# overriding replationship column to show only users with specific role

Tags: laravel, voyager

I created **BREAD** for using voyager with relationship column to display all the users and i want this column to show only users with admin role.

I tried to override the view but I think its wrong choice any help?

```
@if($row->field == 'lead_belongsto_user_relationship')

@endif
```

I can reach the column in the `view/add` view but I don't know how to edit the array of results or how to override the query.

It is showing all the users I want to show only admin list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it Using custom Controllers.
**Steps:**
First create new controller

```
php artisan make:controller LeadController
```

Extend Voyagers controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class LeadController extends \TCG\Voyager\Http\Controllers\VoyagerBaseController
{
    //...
}
?>
```

Finally you can override the relation function from [VoyagerBaseController](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/1.2/src/Http/Controllers/VoyagerBaseController.php#L638)

```
        if($request->type == "lead_belongsto_user_relationship"){
            if ($search) {
                $total_count = app($options->model)->where($options->label, 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->count();
                $relationshipOptions = app($options->model)->take($on_page)->skip($skip)
                    ->where($options->label, 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->where("role_id",3)
                    ->get();
            } else {
                $total_count = app($options->model)->count();
                $relationshipOptions = app($options->model)->take($on_page)->skip($skip)->where("role_id",3)->get();
            }
        }
```

Here i overrided it to select only users with role_id = 3 you can customize it as you need.

> After that go to the BREAD-settings and fill in the Controller Name
>   with your fully-qualified class-name in my case it is
>   "\App\Http\Controllers\LeadController"